# How to calculate UILabel correct line number in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

Sorry, I'm beginner for swift.
First, I have a UITableview and a dynamically UITableViewCell.
And I have a question about calculate line number in my dynamically cell.
I find two UILabel extension answer in Stack, but they don't work for me.
Have any idea to me?
Thanks.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let tableView = UITableView()
let cellNoButton = "cellNoButton"
let cellWithButton = "cellWithButton"
var isExpand: Bool = true
let text = "Students, who translate English texts, do exercises and do tests are very good at translating, doing exercises and doing tests, but they have problems with understanding English in real life. In real life, nobody waits for your translation. People usually use simple English when they speak but they use it fast. You have to understand with no translation to your native language. If you translate, you cannot be part of communication because you are thinking about the language too much. These words are maybe hard to read but they are true.So, if you want to understand English fast and learn fast, read two articles or more a day. You can improve your reading and listening quickly when you read easy English news. We will help you learn English fast and understand it. When you use this website every day, you can learn 3000 words which you need for communication with anybody in English."

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorInset = .zero
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.register(NoButtonTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellNoButton)
    tableView.register(WithButtonTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellWithButton)

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)

    tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.left.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
}
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if isExpand {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellNoButton, for: indexPath) as! NoButtonTableViewCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = text //titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        print("===) \(cell.titleLabel.numberOfVisibleLines)") //it return 1.
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellWithButton, for: indexPath) as! WithButtonTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
}

extension UILabel {
var numberOfVisibleLines: Int {
    let textSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(self.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
    let rHeight: Int = lroundf(Float(self.sizeThatFits(textSize).height))
    let charSize: Int = lroundf(Float(self.font.pointSize))
    return rHeight / charSize
}

func calculateMaxLines() -> Int {
    let maxSize = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(Float.infinity))
    let charSize = font.lineHeight
    let text = (self.text ?? "") as NSString
    let textSize = text.boundingRect(with: maxSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: font], context: nil)
    let linesRoundedUp = Int(ceil(textSize.height/charSize)) 
    return linesRoundedUp
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _calculate line number in my dynamically cell_ ? Do you want to fetch the _row number_ for the cell ?

Comment: For what purpose you required number of lines, what is the use of that?

Comment: I want to calculate the text string whether out of two lines or not. If the text out of two lines, I will use a shrink cell with "show more "button which it can expand and show all text.

Comment: Why don't you use the label height and the font size to compute the number of lines? I don't know if just `label.height / label.font.pointSize` is right, but I am pretty sure that if you `floor` this expression you get the number of lines.

Comment: @VladRusu I find this in Stack. I just take it to use.

Comment: Override `viewDidLayoutSubivews` and print `titleLabel.numberOfVisibleLines` in `NoButtonTableViewCell` class and let us know what you have got there.

Comment: One thing that might not work is that if you want to use it in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` you may not have the frames set to their final values.  You can enforce this by calling `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` before trying to compute the number of lines.

Comment: I’m not sure but, doesn’t `textLabel` of `UITableViewCell` have always `numberOfLines` 0 or 1?

Comment: @VladRusu Yeah, Sorry typed wrongly. I wanted to write the calculated numberOfLines i.e, `numberOfVisibleLines`.

Comment: @Kamran I've seen it edited after writing my comment so I deleted it. I thought I misread it :))

Answer (score 0):

Tryout this code to get number of line

```
extension UILabel {

    func calculateLines() -> Int {
        let maxSize = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(Float.infinity))
        let charSize = font.lineHeight
        let text = (self.text ?? "") as NSString
        let textSize = text.boundingRect(with: maxSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: font], context: nil)
        let linesRoundedUp = Int(ceil(textSize.height/charSize)) 
        return linesRoundedUp
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry, my code already have this. my question is print("===) \(cell.titleLabel.numberOfVisibleLines)"). and give me correct line number, not dynamic cell.

Comment: add extension calculateLines to get number of line.